# What is the volume of a smartie?

Tags: volume

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarties):

> Smarties are oblate spheroids with a minor axis of about 5 mm (0.2 in) and a major axis of about 12 mm (0.5 in).

What is the volume of one smartie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calcutlate the sphere volume with the major radius and then multiply the result by minor/major.

With $r=5/2\text{ mm}$ and $R=12/2\text{ mm}$

$$V=\frac43\pi R^2r=377\;\text{mm}^3$$

Comment: that sounds far too big for a smartie - shouldn't r=2.5mm and R=6mm "radius" not 'diameter"?

Comment: Oh I thougt that would be the radius each. Thx

Comment: I thought smarties were about the size of a shirt button, so those numbers look good. Good to know!